# Frameworks or any Solutions for authentications/security/ login management in Java Web Applications

Tags: java, frameworks, security

I am looking for a framework/solution for authentication/ user-login management/ security  in java web application that can make the naive developer's job easier/faster and make the application relatively more secured against potential threats.

---

P.S. :  I'm using JSF 2.0 as the front-end development framework in my web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/).

You can take a look at their [tutorial](http://shiro.apache.org/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 7):

[Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html) is a reasonable choice.

Comment: I didnt used Spring anywhere in my app but JSF 2.0. How well does it integrate with JSF ?